# parse nested JSON attributes in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

Having trouble which is probably so minor but my searches turn up nothing. I have a json model as follows :

//quick syntax to give you an idea of the model

```
{user:
  {"name": "",
   "password": "",
   "medium" : {
      {"title":"",
      {"description":""}}}
```

I'm getting the above data model from a GET request to user and it returns all the info above but when i try to parse the "medium" information such as "title" & "description" I'm having no luck. I get these responses in Xcode that say

"Value of object 'AnyObject' not unwrapped, did you mean to use ! or ?"

and then when i click on the round red Xcode message to fix it it places !s and ?s everywhere but the error remains. Here is my parse method which worked perfectly fine when I was parsing only from the "medium". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

a portion of the parse method where i get the same error for each attribute:
all lines with the same error indicated by *

```
// Parse JSON data
            let jsonMedium = jsonResult?["user"] as! [AnyObject] //media where user is
            for jsonMedia in jsonMedium {
                let media = Media()
                *media.title = jsonMedia["medium"]["title"] as! String
                *media.description = jsonMedia["medium"]["description"] as! String
                *media.category = jsonMedia["medium"]["category"] as! String
                *media.image = jsonMedia["medium"]["image"] as! String

                *if let IDer = jsonMedia["medium"]["id"] as? Int{
                        var stringIder = String(IDer)
                        media.identifierString = stringIder

                }
```

Still no luck with anything. I don't understand why it works with regular JSON but Xcode won't accept anything when I try to obtain nested. All of your help has been appreciated. In the meantime here's the full method if it helps any further

```
func parseJsonData(data: NSData) -> [Media] {
        var medium = [Media]()
        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
                                                                        options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            // Parse JSON data
            let jsonMedium = jsonResult?["media"] as! [AnyObject]
            for jsonMedia in jsonMedium {
                let media = Media()
                media.title = jsonMedia["medium"]["title"] as! String
                media.description = jsonMedia["medium"]["description"] as! String
                media.category = jsonMedia["medium"]["category"] as! String
                media.image = jsonMedia["medium"]["image"] as! String

                if let IDer = jsonMedia["medium"]["id"] as? Int{
                        var stringIder = String(IDer)
                        media.identifierString = stringIder

                }


                medium.append(media)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return medium
    }
```

Comment: You are getting a syntax error on xcode??

Comment: Yes. The value of object one I described for all of the lines listed with a *

Comment: can you come on skype??

Comment: Occasionally I have to `Product->Clean` after fixing code for Xcode to remove error messages.

Comment: I just tried your code and their is no syntax error jsonResult is AnyObject right?? did u miss the last bracket?? "}"

Answer (score 1):

```
let json = [
    "user" : [
        "name" : "My Name",
        "password" : "My Password",
        "medium" : [
            "title" : "My Title",
            "description" : "My Description"
        ]
    ]
]

if let userJson = json["user"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
    if let name = userJson["name"] as? String {
        print("name: \(name)")
    }
    if let password = userJson["password"] as? String {
        print("password: \(password)")
    }
    if let mediumJson = userJson["medium"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
        if let title = mediumJson["title"] as? String {
            print("title: \(title)")
        }
        if let description = mediumJson["description"] as? String {
            print("description: \(description)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps

```
let request : ASIFormDataRequest = ...your request

        if request.responseString() != nil {
            var jsonResponse : Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?
            do{
                jsonResponse = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(request.responseData(), options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            } catch _ {
                //some error
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT! Took an entire day of deep thought and google/youtube/stack/brainstorming and your help but it was one changed line that got the whole thing going

```
// Parse JSON data
            let jsonMedium = jsonResult?["user"]!["medium"] as? [AnyObject]
            for jsonMedia in jsonMedium! {
                let media = Media()
                media.title = jsonMedia["title"] as! String
                media.description = jsonMedia["description"] as! String
```

instead of :

```
let jsonMedium = jsonResult?["user"] as! [AnyObject] //media where user is
            for jsonMedia in jsonMedium {
                let media = Media()
                *media.title = jsonMedia["medium"]["title"] as! String
                *media.description = jsonMedia["medium"]["description"] as! String
```